# Find smallest number in list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, int, key

I have the following data set:

```
data = 
{
a:[1,2,3]
b:[3,4,5]
c:[5,6,7]
...
}
```

And I am trying to find the smallest number from the index 1 from all the lists.

The only way I could imagine doing it would be this:

```
num = []
index_number = 1

for var in data:
  num.append(data.get(var)[index_number])
return min(num)
```

But i think this is not a very good solution.

Also I will have to find the key that corresponds to the value that i just found.

Is there a good solution that i am not aware of?

Comment: `min(data[x][0] for x in data)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple comprehension may do the trick:

```
>>> data = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [3, 4, 5], 'c': [5, 6, 7]}
>>> index_number = 1
>>> min(((k, v[1]) for k, v in data.items()), key=lambda x: x[1])
('a', 2)
```

If you need only the minimum value, you may use a simpler approach

```
>>> data = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [3, 4, 5], 'c': [5, 6, 7]}
>>> index = 1
>>> min(v[index] for v in data.values())
2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [3, 4, 5], 'c': [5, 6, 7]}
min_key = min(data,key=lambda key:min(data[key]))
```

this tells python you want the "min" value of the data dict, we will use the minimum of each keys list of values as our comparison key in finding the min

Comment: What is the format of data variable that's taken here?  Having trouble using OP's data as data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]].  Get TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list.

Comment: @user391339 its as defined by op in initial problem ... but i updated to include

Comment: Thanks!  I had tried to use theirs but didn't have the single quotes.

Comment: But this would look at all the list items. What is the algorithm for comparing entire lists? 
How would I proceed if I only want to look for the 2nd item?

Comment: then just do `key=lambda key:data[key][2]`